# How to use a variable for a hash table key in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, hashtable, ecmascript-5

I'd like to use a variable that contains the key value for a hash table in Google Apps Script.

In place of:

```
var folderRoots = {
  "EYFS English":"sdfg0987897sdfga3",
  "EYFS Italian":"sdf8f9g7897sfdfg7",  
  }

var b = folderRoots["EYFS English"]; // gets sdfg0987897sdfga3
```

I would like to use:

```
var depEYFSEn = "EYFS English";
var depEYFSIt = "EYFS Italian";

var folderRoots = {
  [depEYFSEn]:"sdfg0987897sdfga3",
  [depEYFSIt]:"sdf8f9g7897sfdfg7",  
  }

var b = folderRoots[depEYFSEn]; // gets sdfg0987897sdfga3
```

However, when attempting to use square brackets for the key variable as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36024066/367032), the editor will throw an error

> **Invalid property ID**

Maybe Google Apps Script Javascript implementation does not support this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) are a feature in ES6, and Google Apps Script is still at ES5.

Instead, you can create your keys from your variables by setting the key on the object using [bracket notation `[]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation):

```js
var depEYFSEn = "EYFS English";
var depEYFSIt = "EYFS Italian";

var folderRoots = {};
folderRoots[depEYFSEn] = "sdfg0987897sdfga3";
folderRoots[depEYFSIt] = "sdf8f9g7897sfdfg7";


var b = folderRoots[depEYFSEn]; // gets sdfg0987897sdfga3
console.log(b);
```